# What is properway to specify numpy masked array maksed value?

Tags: python, numpy

I basically want to run something like the following

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a = ma.masked_array(x, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0])

for i in range(5):
   if (a[i] == "--"):
      print("a[{0:d}] is masked value".format(i))
```

I am not sure how I should specify the `--` value of the masked array in the `if (a[i] == "--")` part where `"--"` is something that I could not figure out. I know there are few other ways of doing it by processing the entire masked array into a boolean values, but I don't want that.

Edit.

The array `a` is an masked array, and when I print it out I get

```
masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3, --, 5],
             mask=[False, False, False,  True, False],
       fill_value=999999)
```

What I want to do is to skip the `--` values in that output using the `if` statement.

Comment: `a = [--,--,0,1,2]` is not a numpy array, but a plain list, and also wrong since `--` is wrong syntax in python. Also your `for` loop is likely wrong, why do you compare `a` with ``"--"``?

Comment: I know it is a python list, I just wanted to demonstrate it. If you want me to change it and be technical about it, I will change it.

Comment: I think it would help to understand your question if you make it more technical, yes. It would be definitely more useful to people who know python but are not expert in numpy.

Answer (score 1):

A masked array has two key attributes, `data` and `mask`.

```
In [63]: a.mask
Out[63]: array([False, False, False,  True, False])
In [64]: a.data
Out[64]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

`getmask` docs say its equivalent to getting the attribute:

```
In [65]: np.ma.getmask(a)
Out[65]: array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```

That mask can then be used to select values from `data`:

```
In [66]: a.data[a.mask]
Out[66]: array([4])
```

More commonly we are interested in the unmasked values:

```
In [67]: a.compressed()
Out[67]: array([1, 2, 3, 5])
```

After all if using masking, we aren't "supposed" to care about the masked values.  The compressed ones can be used to take the sum:

```
In [68]: a.sum()
Out[68]: 11
```

Alternatively the masked values can be filled with something innocuous

```
In [69]: a.filled()
Out[69]: array([     1,      2,      3, 999999,      5])
In [70]: a.filled(0)
Out[70]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way should be:

```
mask_a = numpy.ma.getmask(a)
```

which following your example returns the mask array:

```
array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```

If I understand correctly how numpy works internally, this does not "process" the masked array to get boolean out of it. The mask *is* already there, you are just getting it in a proper array which can be used in your `for` loop, so if you are worried about performance... don't worry.

```
for i in range(5):
    if mask_a[i]:
        print("a[{0:d}] is masked value".format(i))
```

---

However, if for whatever reason you don't want to use the `getmask` function, you can get the string representation of `a`.

```
str_a = str(a)
```

which in your example is: `'[1 2 3 -- 5]'`

Then you can strip the square brackets and split the string on white spaces:

```
str_a = str(a)[1:-1].split()
```

which in your example is `['1', '2', '3', '--', '5']`.

Then you have a list where you can filter out the `"--"` values with your `for` loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    if str_a[i] == "--":
        print("a[{0:d}] is masked value".format(i))
```

But honestly, using the `getmask` function should be the way to go: I didn't profile it, but I expect it to be faster.